# Blaze and SiteMinder example

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, blazeds, siteminder

I'm just looking for some direction to integrate my Flex app with SiteMinder. I can't find any working examples online to get me started.

Thanks for any tips in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

blaze ds operates over HTTP and will inherit your site minder cookies that you established when downloading the swf i believe. we do this at work. So make sure your .swf file is in a protected folder so you have an established siteminder session and then ensure that the blazeds mapped url /messagebroker or whatever is also protected.